# Encrypting Draft to Create Linked Service for Azure Data Factory Results in Error.

Tags: sql-server, azure, connection-string, azure-data-factory

I am trying to encrypt a draft to Create a Linked service in Azure Data Factory, but when i click the encrypt button and try to click on the client that gest downloaded i get an error.

So first i skipped inputting my username and password because Microsofts guide doesn't tell me to, for some reason (BTW that one needs to be updated...)

Guide: [Move data between on-premises sources and the cloud with Data Management Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-move-data-between-onprem-and-cloud)

The first error i get is one saying:

> "Property 'connectionString' is not valid. Cannot encrypt credentials."

Ok, so i try input my windows login credentials..
It works to the point of it downloading the Credentials client.

And when i launch the application it says "Cannot start application"
I lick on the details button and baically it gives me the error:

> "Deployment and application do not have matching security zones."

With these details in a notepad file:

```
ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [2017-10-20 14:44:40] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (Zone)
        - Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I managed to solve this problem, I had to do the whole draft and encrypt it in EDGE Browser...
For some reason this particurlar client doesn't work with Firefox or Chrome.